# css pulling from the wrong location with {{ STATIC_URL }} on my form page only

Tags: django

I'm using django 1.3

I'm using a base.html template which my pages inherit from. Everything works fine except for one page (which has a form on it).
That page is trying to call the CSS from `/links/addlink/css/site.css` but this is the wrong location. It is in `/static/css/site.css`

In my base.html I have `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/site.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />`

If I create a completely seperate template and use the full path like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/site.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />` then my page renders correctly.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `RequestContext`in your view.

See here: [Referring to static files in templates](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#referring-to-static-files-in-templates)